User does not have access to object, but can still insert and update data in apex
Currently I have a user with a profile that does not have edit and create permissions, including permission set. But when calling into apex, it still inserts and updates data.
Can anyone explain to me?
public static void createAccount(String accountName) {
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = accountName;
    insert acc;
}


Anonymous Apex runs in user mode by default, any other Apex code (trigger, batch, etc...) runs in System Mode. Documentation is very clear about it:

Apex code runs in system mode by default, which means that it runs with substantially elevated permissions over the user running the code.

That's why your user is able to run that code.
If you want to enforce user permissions (and you should), just change the insert statement either to insert as user acc; or Database.insert(acc, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);, this way if an user does't have the required permission, that dml will throw an exception.
It's also imporant to test your code accordingly, using System.runAs().
If you want to enforce permissions and visibility while running a query, you should add WITH USER_MODE after the WHERE clause (if any), i.e.
[SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account WITH USER_MODE]
[SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account WHERE Type = NULL WITH USER_MODE]
[SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account WHERE Type = NULL WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY Name]

Please note that objects/fields permissions and sharing are not the same. While the sharing rules are enforced in user mode, if you run a query in system mode, record visibility is controlled by the [with|without|inherited] sharing clause on the class, see related docs

While I agree that your should ensure the code considers permissions (and sharing) explicitly, in the way shown here, I would go a step further. Instead of waiting for a DML exception to be thrown, you should improve the UX by ensuring that the action (that runs the logic that ends up inserting/updating/deleting stuff) is enabled only when the user has the required permissions.

@PhilW Fully agree with you. A lightning page could be customized with visibility rules to show actions only to users with the right permissions and from a LWC checking for object/custom permissions requires few lines of code.

If only formulas provided access to check standard CRUD/FLS permissions. Only custom permissions are currently supported (this is, IMHO, a product gap on the platform). You'd probably have to deal with this in code somehow.
